# Is it possible to find files by wildcard and not substring in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, wildcards

When I search for files in my Windows Explorer by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>, I tell it the file name, and it looks in current folder and all subfolders. However, it looks like Windows tries to match filenames by substring, which gives me unwanted files.

For example, I have many files with numbers in their names:

```
..._1.txt
..._2.txt
...
..._10.txt
..._11.txt
...
..._99.txt
```

I have more than one file with number `1`, in more than one subdirectory, and I want to find them all. However, Windows offers me all files with numbers 10...19, which I don't want.

Here is a screenshot where I recreated this problem in a folder which contains just a few files:

```
file1.txt
file10.txt
file2.txt
file8.txt
```

[image: example]

Can I make Windows Explorer find only the files I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes around what you're searching for. For example, searching for `"file1.txt"` will only show `file1.txt`. You can also use wildcards in this, `"*1.txt"` will give you all files that end with `1.txt` and start with whatever.

Update (thanks @DavidPostill): If you need a wildcard for just one character, using `?` will work. Ex. searching for `"file?1.txt"` will return `file01.txt` and `file21.txt` but not `file1231.txt`, whereas the `*` will.

Comment: `file?.txt` is better as it will match only 1 number ... (and any other single character of course).

Comment: Using the question mark *with* the double quotes is what I think @DavidPostill was going for. It works as a wildcard for a single character.